# JavaScript only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript that seems to only run once. I am using this to select the colour of a letter inside a div. When I select the colour initially it works but then will not select a different colour.

This is the select:

```
 <div style = "position: absolute; left: 360px; top: 590px;" >    
 <select id="selectcolor1" name="selectcolor1" style="width: 150px;">
                    <option value="null">Select a Motif Color...</option>
                    <option value="black">Black</option>
                    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                    <option value="darkblue">Dark Blue</option>
                    <option value="pink">Pink</option>
                    <option value="green">Green</option>
                    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
                    <option value="seagreen">Sea Green</option>
                    <option value="red">Red</option>
                    <option value="darkgreen">Dark Green</option>
                    <option value="bergundy">Bergundy</option>
                    <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
                    <option value="magenta">Magenta</option>
                    <option value="mustard">mustard</option>
                    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
```

This is the javascript:

```
 $('#selectcolor1').change(function() {
var color = this.value || '';
$('.selectcolor1').attr('class', function(i, classes) {
    var cls = classes.split(/[\s]/);
    cls[2] = color;
    return cls.join(' ');
});
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

I probably should have mentioned I am using the script to change to different Div's colours apologies my fault:

```
      <div style = "position: absolute; left: 750px; top: 313px;" 
class="selected-value  selectcolor1" id ="motif" ></div>


<div style = "position: absolute; left: 750px; top: 313px;" 
class="selected-value1 selectcolor1" id ="motif1" ></div>
```

Any help would be great thank you!

Comment: you're not passing in your event (e) to the preventDefault

Comment: Hey cport1 sorry could you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: @cport1 is right. That is likely triggering a fatal error and not allowing you to run the JS function again.

Comment: pass `e` as and argument: `$('#selectcolor1').change(function(e) { .... e.preventDefault(); }`

Comment: by the way: do you really have one tag with an id _selectcolor1_ (selector starting with #) and another, not visible in the given code block, with a class name _selectcolor1_ (selector starting with . )?

Comment: Look at your javascript console. `e` is not defined.

Comment: Here's a helpful hint: always check your favorite browser's developer console before posting a question.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work but I have just had a thought. I am using the same scrip to to change the colour of another div. Could it be that once it runs once it pass' the script to the other div permanently?

Answer (score 5):

Couple of problems here.

As @cport noted, you are not declaring the `e` variable you are referring to in `e.preventDefault()`. This needs to come in the `change` function handler.

As @dsuess noted, your code is changing the class on a tag with class="selectcolor1", which isn't in your pasted code - please make sure this is correct.

Also, this code will work with [the jsfiddle provided below](http://jsfiddle.net/yuab9jL9/2/) since it sets the target's third class and the target has two classes initially. However, if you change the target HTML to have three or more classes from the start, the Javascript code will overwrite the third class.

But having said that, this works with the current code:

```
$('#selectcolor1').change(function(e) {
    var color = this.value || '';
    $('.selectcolor1').attr('class', function(i, classes) {
        var cls = classes.split(/[\s]/);
        cls[2] = color; // third class becomes the color value
        return cls.join(' ');
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle with an example of working vs non-working.  Made it much easier to find my fault.

Answer (score 2):

As @cport1 stated, the anonymous function is missing the `e` parameter:

```
$('#selectcolor1').change(function(e) { ...
```

This will cause the JS to be fired only once and then error because there is no reference to `e` in that function's scope.

Comment: At least post what they should change it to.

Comment: I feel this answers OP question, but @Jarek answer offers a better implementation.

Comment: @MattBurland - My bad. I meant to, but I guess I forgot it.

Comment: @skube - @Jarek's answer doesn't answer OP's question directly or intentionally. It just so happens to include the `e` parameter, but offers no explanation as to why. Jarek does offer some helpful info, but not any that fixes OP's issue.

Comment: Sorry guys, you're correct - I started off changing the implementation for setting the class and then added in the `e` without explanation. I've edited my comment to hopefully be a bit better!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `e` parameter in your event binding:

```
 $('#selectcolor1').change(function()
```

replace with

```
 $('#selectcolor1').change(function(e)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work but I have just had a thought. I am using the same scrip to to change the colour of another div. Could it be that once it runs once it pass' the script to the other div permanently?

Comment: It should work. can you send the fiddle link? 
And your thought can be good enough.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yuab9jL9/

thats a js fiddle so far I am just struggling to get the dive to display in it

Comment: @MattLuka move the `<div>` with class selectcolor1 from CSS to HTML box. I changed that and it seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/yuab9jL9/2/